# tkinter entry into SQL Query

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to take an entry from tkinter and use that entry in an SQL query.

```
def rn():
cursor = con.cursor()
query1 =('SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM DATABASE  WHERE NAME LIKE (?)', WN.get())
df_ora3 = pd.read_sql(query1, con=con)    
print(df_ora3)

    #create text boxes
v = StringVar()
WN = Entry(self, textvariable=v,width = 30)
WN.grid(row =0,column=1, padx = 20)
WN_label = Label(self, text ="Name:")
WN_label.grid(row=0,column=0)


btn1 = Button(self, text ="Load Coordinates", command = rn)
btn1.grid(row = 2, column =0)
```

but I get the following error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '('SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM DATABASE  WHERE NAME LIKE (?)', WN.get()), 'Taco Shop')': expecting string or bytes object
```

When I declare a = the entry and print it, it's just called .!entry. But I thought I forced the entry to become a string, and the error says expecting string. Any thoughts on how to get it to take my entry?

UPDATE: Got it to work by changing the query in the following way:

```
 query1 =("('SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM DATABASE  WHERE NAME LIKE  ('%s')"%(WN.get()))
```

Comment: Try something like ab = a.get()

Comment: You probably need to supply the query string and the Entry contents as *separate parameters* to your database call.  Currently, you are passing them as a single tuple.